Github Access Issue in Android Studio
This is the issue I am getting in Android while sharing project in the GitHub.

I have already tried this: recreated the token and logged in with that token in android but it still fails. And i have also tried to login via github that too fails: one thing is that when i click on login via github it redirects me to jetbrains website and I authroize from there becuase i created the jetbrain account with github.
These are the scope of token that i used:

By looking at the error I have doubt that there might be network related issue but I am unable to solve that.
Update:
I have checked proxy setting in Android Studio under system settings>HTTP proxy. Here no proxy is selected and on checking connection I entered my github account url and it says connection is successful.

Updating my Android Studio from Iguana 2023.2 to Koala 2024.1.1 has done the trick for me.
